# Простой вопрос по PHP

Tags: php

Почему

```
if (0 == 'none')
```

выдает `true`?

p.s. php 5.3

Comment: Потому, что число и логическая переменная - это разные вещи. **Asen** вам правильно показал. Почитайте о логических операторах http://php.su/learnphp/operators/?compar

Comment: так то понял, он приводит строку к числовому типу и получается 0.
p.s.
число в логическом сравнении остается числом :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (0 === 'none')
```

Answer (score 0):

для того чтобы точно приводить к тому типу который надо можно ваше условие написать так:

```
if (0 == (int)'none')...
```

также:

```
echo (int)'none';
```

вам как раз выдаст 0